# Minimum of $\cos^2(x) (\csc^2(\frac{\pi}{2n} - \frac{x}{n}) + \csc^2(\frac{\pi}{2n} + \frac{x}{n}))$ for $0 \leq x < \pi/2$ and $n \geq 3$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry, optimization

I am trying to proove that $x=0$ is the minimum point of the function
$$f(x) = \cos^2(x)\left( \csc^2(x_+) + \csc^2(x_-) \right)$$
in the interval $0 \leq x < \pi/2$ where $x_\pm = \frac\pi{2n} \pm \frac x n$,
and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq 3$.

I have unsuccessfully tried the following approaches.

1. Attempted to show that $f(x) - f(0) \geq 0$, i.e.
   $$\cos^2(x)\left(
       \csc^2\left(\frac\pi{2n} - \frac x n\right) +
       \csc^2\left(\frac\pi{2n} + \frac x n\right)
   \right) - 2\csc^2\left(\frac\pi{2n}\right) \geq 0;$$
2. Computed $f'(x) = \frac\partial{\partial x} f(x)$ and tried to show that $f'(x) \geq 0$ in the interval, where
   \begin{align}
   \frac\partial{\partial x} f(x) = 2\cos^2(x) \left(
       \frac{1}{n} \cot(x_-)\csc^2(x_-) - 
       \frac{1}{n} \cot(x_+)\csc^2(x_+) -
       \tan(x)\left(\csc^2(x_-) + \csc^2(x_+)\right)
   \right);
   \end{align}
3. Used Taylor Series Expansion in $f(x)$ attempting to find a tight lower bound for $f(x)$.

Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Proof**:

We need to prove that $f(x) \ge f(0) = 2\csc^2\frac{\pi}{2n}$ for all $0 \le x < \frac{\pi}{2}$.

---

If $n = 3$, we have
$$f(x) = - 16\left(\cos^2 \frac{x}{3} - \frac34\right)^2 + 9 \ge 8 = 2\csc^2 \frac{\pi}{6}$$
where we have used $\frac{3}{4} \le \cos^2 \frac{x}{3} \le 1$.

---

In the following, assume that $n \ge 4$.

We have
$$f(x) = \cos^2 x \cdot 
\frac{2\cos\frac{\pi}{n}\sin^2 \frac{x}{n} + 2\sin^2 \frac{\pi}{2n}}{(\sin^2 \frac{\pi}{2n} - \sin^2 \frac{x}{n})^2}.$$

*Fact 1*: $\sin \frac{x}{n} \ge \frac{2}{\pi} x \sin \frac{\pi}{2n}$.
(*Hint*: Take derivative.)

*Fact 2*: $\cos^2 x \cdot 
\frac{4x^2\pi^2\cos \frac{\pi}{4} + \pi^4}{\left(\pi^2 - 4x^2 \right)^2} \ge 1$.
(The proof is given at the end.)

By using Fact 1, we have
\begin{align*}
 f(x) &\ge \cos^2 x \cdot 
 \frac{2\cos\frac{\pi}{n}\cdot (\frac{2}{\pi} x \sin \frac{\pi}{2n})^2 + 2\sin^2 \frac{\pi}{2n}}{\left[\sin^2 \frac{\pi}{2n} - (\frac{2}{\pi} x \sin \frac{\pi}{2n} )^2\right]^2}\\[5pt]
 &= 2\csc^2\frac{\pi}{2n} \cdot \cos^2 x \cdot 
 \frac{\frac{4x^2}{\pi^2}\cos\frac{\pi}{n} + 1}{\left(1 - \frac{4x^2}{\pi^2} \right)^2}\\[5pt]
 &\ge 2\csc^2\frac{\pi}{2n} \cdot \cos^2 x \cdot 
 \frac{\frac{4x^2}{\pi^2}\cos \frac{\pi}{4} + 1}{\left(1 - \frac{4x^2}{\pi^2} \right)^2}\\[5pt]
 &\ge 2\csc^2\frac{\pi}{2n} \tag{1}
\end{align*}
where we have used Fact 2 to obtain (1).

We are done.

---

*Proof of Fact 2*:

*Fact 3*: $\cos x \ge \frac{2\pi^2 - 16}{\pi^4}x^4 - \frac{1}{2}x^2 + 1 \ge 0$ for all $0 \le x < \pi/2$.
(The proof is given at the end.)

By using Fact 3, it suffices to prove that
$$\left(\frac{2\pi^2 - 16}{\pi^4}x^4 - \frac{1}{2}x^2 + 1\right)^2\cdot \frac{4x^2\pi^2\cos \frac{\pi}{4} + \pi^4}{\left(\pi^2 - 4x^2 \right)^2} \ge 1$$
or
$$\frac{x^2}{4\pi^6}(Ax^4 + Bx^2 + C) \ge 0$$
where
\begin{align*}
 A &= 2\,\sqrt{2}\, {\pi }^{4}-32\,\sqrt {2}\,{\pi }^{2}+128\,\sqrt {2}, \\
 B &= {\pi }^{6}-8\,\sqrt{2}\,{\pi }^{4}-16\,{\pi }^{4}+64\,\sqrt{2}\,{\pi }^{
  2}+64\,{\pi }^{2}
 ,\\
 C &= -4\,{\pi }^{6}+8\,\sqrt {2}\,{\pi }^{4}+32\,{\pi }^{4}.
\end{align*}
It is easy to prove that $Ax^4 + Bx^2 + C \ge 0$ for all $0 \le x < \pi/2$.

We are done.

---

*Proof of Fact 3*:

We split into two cases:

1. $0 \le x \le \pi/3$:

It is easy to prove that
$$\cos x \ge 1 - \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{1}{24}x^4 - \frac{1}{720}x^6.$$
It suffices to prove that
$$1 - \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{1}{24}x^4 - \frac{1}{720}x^6 \ge \frac{2\pi^2 - 16}{\pi^4}x^4 - \frac{1}{2}x^2 + 1$$
which is true (easy).

2. $\frac{\pi}{3} < x < \pi/2$:

It is easy to prove that
$$\cos x \ge - \left(x - \frac{\pi}{2}\right) + \frac{1}{6}\left(x - \frac{\pi}{2}\right)^3.$$
It suffices to prove that
$$- \left(x - \frac{\pi}{2}\right) + \frac{1}{6}\left(x - \frac{\pi}{2}\right)^3
\ge \frac{2\pi^2 - 16}{\pi^4}x^4 - \frac{1}{2}x^2 + 1$$
which is true (easy).

We are done.

Comment: This is an elegant solution. Now I'm trying to prove that Fact 2 is indeed true. I may be wrong, but it appears to me that the difficulty of the problem was transferred to Fact 2. Would you have any hint or material that could help me?

Comment: @Koruja My proof for Fact 2 is not nice. I will post it soon.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to proove that $x=0$ corresponds to $\large \color{red}{a}$ minimum point is not so difficult if you make a Taylor expansion of
$$f_n(x)=\cos ^2(x) \left(\csc ^2\left(\frac{\pi -2 x}{2 n}\right)+\csc ^2\left(\frac{\pi+2
   x }{2 n}\right)\right)$$
$$f_n(x)=2 \csc ^2\left(\frac{\pi }{2 n}\right)\Bigg[1+ \left(\frac{1+3 \cot ^2\left(\frac{\pi }{2
   n}\right)}{n^2}-1\right)x^2+O\left(x^4\right) \Bigg]$$ So, we have
$$f_n(0)=2 \csc ^2\left(\frac{\pi }{2 n}\right)\qquad f'_n(0)=0\qquad f''_n(0)=\frac{2 \left(\left(n^2+2\right) \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{n}\right)+4-n^2\right)
   \csc ^4\left(\frac{\pi }{2 n}\right)}{n^2}$$ and
$$f''_n(0) > 0 \qquad \text{     } \qquad \forall n \quad \geq 3$$

Comment: I thought about that approach, but as you stressed, it only wields a local minumum (not global).